# Insert values into a new table with Join condition

Tags: sql

I don't know how to do following.

I have created new table name.table1

And I like to insert specific columns into the new table.
This is the code I tried to use but it didn't work.

```
Insert into name.table1
SELECT 
account.STRING0,
activity.CONTACT,
account.STRING2,
activity.TEMPLATE,
activity.NAME ,
activity.EXECUTION, 
activity.SENDDATE,
Activity.OPENDATE,
Activity.CLICKDATE
FROM  
    db.1_account account 
Join 
    db.2_activity activity 
    ON 
     (account.object = activity.contact)
 left JOIN 
    db.VAL val1 
       ON val1.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN AND (val1.FIELD in(850)) 
left JOIN 
    db.VAL val2 
       ON val2.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN AND (val2.FIELD in(851))
```

Something is wrong with this insert Query, but I could not find out what.

Comment: Are you trying to create new table from select query results or you are trying to insert the result into existing table. Also mention the `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: (1) Tag the question with your database. (2) Edit the question and include the error you are getting.  (3) Show the structure of `table1` or include the columns for `table1` in the `insert`.

Comment: I created blank table just for this insert so I could get all the columns data into new blank table

Comment: I Understand that I need to define new table aka Create table with right parameters But which commands I need to give these parameters: Following string0 = integer , String2 = char 255, Contact = char 255, template = char 255, name = char 255 , Execution = char 255, Senddate = timestamp, Opendate = timestamp , clickdate = timestamp

Comment: I created table with following parameters:
create TABLE db.TEST1
(
STRING0 INTEGER ,
CONTACT char(255),
EXT_STRING2 char(255),
TEMPLATE char(255),
NAME char(255),
EXECUTION char(255), 
SENDDATE TIMESTAMP ,
OPENDATE TIMESTAMP,
CLICKDATE TIMESTAMP,
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, You want to create new table from result. Use `INTO` clause

```
SELECT 
account.STRING0,
activity.CONTACT,
account.STRING2,
activity.TEMPLATE,
activity.NAME ,
activity.EXECUTION, 
activity.SENDDATE,
Activity.OPENDATE,
Activity.CLICKDATE INTO NEW_TABLE
FROM  
    db.1_account account 
Join 
    db.2_activity activity 
    ON 
     (account.object = activity.contact)
....
```

Comment: When I do like this
It gives me an error on the second line that STRING0 not found.
Do I have to make all the columns before into the new table.
Aka add manually these columns to new table Or what should I do?

Comment: do you have a column named `STRING0` in your new table

Comment: Not yet, I hoped that I could do this with one query to import the data and bring the columns to new table

Comment: @meelismelx433 - Which RDBMS you are using like `Sql server, Orcale, Mysql, Postgre, etc..`

Comment: I am useing Sybase SQL Server

Comment: I Understand that I need to define new table with right parameters
But which commands I need to give these parameters:
Following string0 = integer , String2 = char 255, Contact = char 255, template = char 255, name = char 255 , Execution = char 255, Senddate = timestamp, Opendate = timestamp , clickdate = timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Creating a blank table has nothing to do with not mentioning the columns while inserting the data into the table.

You say you want to insert into specific columns but nowhere have you mentioned the column names of the table into which you are inserting data.

Any ways, presuming that this is what you want to achieve, I hope the below code helps you.

```
Insert into name.table1(yourcolumn1,yourcolumn2,...)SELECT account.STRING0, activity.CONTACT,account.STRING2,activity.TEMPLATE,activity.NAME ,activity.EXECUTION,activity.SENDDATE,Activity.OPENDATE,Activity.CLICKDATE FROM  
db.1_account account Join 
db.2_activity activity 
ON 
 (account.object = activity.contact) left JOIN 
db.VAL val1 
   ON val1.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN AND (val1.FIELD in(850)) left JOIN  db.VAL val2 
   ON val2.obj_row_id = activity.CAMPAIGN AND (val2.FIELD in(851))
```